# How we can set table properties for delta table in pyspark using DeltaTable API

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

Below is the code that I am trying in PySpark

```
from delta import DeltaTable

delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path)
delta_table.logRetentionDuration = "interval 1 days"
```

After this do we need to save this config or it will be applicable automatically. How we can check what is current logRetentionDuration set for table.
I tried below to get properties info

```
delta_table.detail()
```

But it return empty {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Spark SQL:

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE delta.`path\to\delta\table` SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.logRetentionDuration'='1 days')")
```

```
spark.sql("DESCRIBE DETAIL delta.`path\to\delta\table\path`").show(truncate=False)
```

Under the ***"properties"*** column you can see the log retention duration of the specified delta table.

Note: If the retention period was not set properly, the above SQL command returns `{}` in the properties column.

Comment: I did that it return {} in properties column.

Comment: Try this `spark.sql("ALTER TABLE delta.\`path\to\delta\table\` SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.logRetentionDuration'='1 days')")` and then use the decribe command.

Comment: Thanks it set property. I accept answer. Is there any API option to do the same using DeltaTable object.